# What are the best practices in order to add custom semantic markup to XForms?

Tags: semantic-markup, orbeon, xforms

Greetings to all Orbeon's folks,

I would like to add custom xml semantic markup to a XForms using Orbeon.
For instance, adding the tag or the property "person".

So do I have to create new tags or properties or both? What is the best practice? Considering differences between marking-up structures and marking-up elements?

Where can I put semantic markup without disturbing the behaviour of the Orbeon engine and still being able to access to it? I think it should be in the model declaration? Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: From my actual knowledge of XForms, it could be done putting custom semantic markup into the model declarative part  

<xforms:model> 
   <xforms:instance> 
      <person> 
         <name/> <email/> ... </person>  </xforms:instance> </xforms:model> and referring it into the controller part using a ref attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [label or hint](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-other-extensions#TOC-Standalone-label-hint-help-and-alert-elements) elements to add metadata which is hidden or context-sensitive. Use [placeholders](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/01/use-html5-placeholders-in-xforms.html) to show that data as an annotation:

```
<xforms:label appearance="minimal">Your name</xforms:label>
```